# trac with subversion post-commit to update web folder

Tags: svn, trac, post-commit

I'm trying to setup the post-commit hook of my subversion to update after every commit our development servers web folder. I have been following this instructions  [SVN SSH post-commit checkout hook](http://www.bennyn.de/programmierung/c/svn-ssh-post-commit-checkout-hook.html) (is in German, but the codes are commented in English) but unfortunately doesn't seems to work. After the commits the log file is initialized but the update won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to modify this line of the script:

```
/srv/svn/repos/st38/hooks/bin/svn-update /usr/bin/svn /srv/www/st38
```

to write the output of the svn-update command also to the logfile

```
/srv/svn/repos/st38/hooks/bin/svn-update /usr/bin/svn /srv/www/st38 2>&1 >> /srv/www/st38/post-commit.log
```

also try to manually execute that line.

Comment: Hi! If I'm executing manually the bash post-commit, the web folder is going to be updated. I think is a permission problem but I don't really find the source of it.

Comment: @lgt is there an error message in the logfile (after you changed the script)?

Comment: no everything looks okay. Is going to output the revision number. But only if I'm calling the script manually.

Comment: so I'm sure now that the problem is coming from permissions set up. If I'm executing the bash command with a user who is member of the svn group than the permission is denied.

Comment: you can try to modify the rights of the svn-update command the following way: find a user/group which can execute the svn command, for example your own account, execute `chown user:group path/to/svn-update` and `chmod 6777 path/to/svn-update`, but this would allow everybody to execute the svn-update command.